# Squish Fields Together If Blank Space in BizTalk

Tags: xsd, position, mapping, biztalk

```
0000103100USD0.00        000000000000.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000      00000000000000
0000051400USD0.00        000000000000.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000      00000000000000
```

I'm new to BizTalk, so I'm not sure if this is a common thing that can be solved by flipping an attribute around, or if I need to handle this in the map itself.

I have a map that outputs a flat file that looks something like this. What I need is for all of the blank space between fields to disappear.

I've had an idea to check the length of each string with 0's in it and add 0's to the front for the numbers e.g. 0000000.00, but certainly BT has an easier solution... I would think.

Comment: Is your output positional or delimited?  If it is positional you don't wan't to get rid of the spaces as then fields will be out of position.  If it is delimited, what are your delimiters?  It also helps if you give us a sample schema showing what you have tried and a sample XML file so people can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using Padding, Padding Character, and Justification to get to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the blank spaces are not blank, they are actually part of your data. You could use xslt to trim the input text if you want to get rid of the white spaces.

Comment: That's true, but I needed it for a mainframe file. In this instance, it didn't care about it being squished together.